# React. как корректно хранить состояние?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, компоненты

Пишу виджет комментариев, нужно реализовать возможность сворачивание ветки с дочерними комментариями. На входе имеется json, который с помощью d3 парсится в дерево в методе updateState, далее эти данные рекурсивно отрисовываются, сначала первый родительский коммент, далее все его дети, затем второй родительский и так далее (функция renderRow). Проблема в том, что я не знаю, где хранить состояние свернутости CommentItem (непосредственно, сам блок комментария), чтобы в теле рекурсии я мог знать, свернут ли он, чтобы не добавлять его в массив, который пойдет в рендер.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchComments } from '../../../redux/actions'
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import CommentItem from '../CommentItem'

const RenderRow = ({ comments }) => {
  const array = []

  const recursive = (comments, depth = 0) => {
    comments.forEach(comment => {
      array.push(
        <CommentItem
          depth={comment.parent.id === '0' ? 0 : depth}
          key={comment.id}
          comment={comment.data}
        />
      )
      if (comment.children) {
        depth += 1
        recursive(comment.children, depth)
      }
      depth -= 1
    })
  }
  if (comments.length > 0) {
    recursive(comments)
  }
  return (array)
}

class CommentList extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      comments: []
    }
  }

  updateState = () => {
    const stratify = d3.stratify()
      .id(d => d.id)
      .parentId(d => d.parentId)

    const structuredComments = stratify(this.props.comments)

    this.setState({ comments: [...structuredComments.children] })
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.fetchComments()
    this.updateState()
  }

  componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    const prevComments = prevProps.comments
    const currComments = this.props.comments
    const newComments = (
      prevComments.filter(i => currComments.indexOf(i) < 0)
        .concat(currComments.filter(i => prevComments.indexOf(i) < 0))
    )

    if (newComments[0]) {
      this.updateState()
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (<RenderRow comments={this.state.comments}/>)
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ comments }) => ({ comments })

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchComments }
)(CommentList)
```

Comment: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

Comment: @exvayn вопрос в том, как я могу взять состояние дочернего элемента, чтобы знать в родителе, нужно ли мне его пушить в массив

Comment: судя по коду, Вы используете redux, соответственно в `store` можно сохранить необходимые сведения